# string array in string.xml in Android

Tags: android

I want to create a string array in string.xml in values folder for my android application. How to do this.. can anybody help..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="my_array">
        <item>string1</item>
        <item>string2</item>
        <item>string3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```