# android:array index out of bound exception

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, crash

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView lvSlidingMenu;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle; // Navigation Drawer titles
    private CharSequence drawerTitle;
    private CharSequence appTitle;

    // Sliding Menu items
    private String[] titles;
    private TypedArray icons;
    private ArrayList slidingMenuItems;
    private SlidingMenuAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        appTitle = drawerTitle = getTitle();

        // Load resources
        titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        // Get Sliding Menu ListView istance
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        lvSlidingMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_sliding_menu);
        slidingMenuItems = new ArrayList();

        // Creating and Adding SlidingMenuItems
        slidingMenuItems.add(new SlidingMenuItem(titles[0], icons.getResourceId(0,-1)));
        slidingMenuItems.add(new SlidingMenuItem(titles[1], icons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        slidingMenuItems.add(new SlidingMenuItem(titles[2], icons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        slidingMenuItems.add(new SlidingMenuItem(titles[3], icons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        icons.recycle();
        lvSlidingMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // Assign adapter to listview
        adapter = new SlidingMenuAdapter(getApplicationContext(), slidingMenuItems);
        lvSlidingMenu.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Enable action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer
                // Navigation Drawer
               , R.string.app_name,
                //Navigation Drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name)
                // Navigation Drawer close - description for accessibility
         {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(appTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(drawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }; drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // On first time, show Home Fragment
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener *
     */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Display appropriate fragment for selected item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Toggle Navigation Drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    } /* * * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered */

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If Navigation Drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(lvSlidingMenu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Display fragment view for selected Navigation Drawer list item *
     */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_detail, fragment).commit();

            // Update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            lvSlidingMenu.setItemChecked(position, true);
            lvSlidingMenu.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(titles[position]);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(lvSlidingMenu);
        } else {
            // Log error
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        appTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(appTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivty.java

```
public class SlidingMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SlidingMenuItem> items;

    public SlidingMenuAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SlidingMenuItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return items.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.iv_item_sliding_menu, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_sliding_menu_item);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sliding_menu_item);

        SlidingMenuItem item = items.get(index);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(item.getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());

        return view;
    }

}
```

This is my adapter.java file

```
public class SlidingMenuItem {
    String title;
    int icon;

    public SlidingMenuItem(String title, int icon) {
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

}
```

And this is my menu item

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name" translatable="false">Fb slid</string>

    <string name="hello_world" translatable="false">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings" translatable="false">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main" translatable="false">MainActivity
    </string>


        <!-- Sliding Menu items -->
 <string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item >Home</item>
    <item >Notifications</item>
    <item >Settings</item>
    <item >About</item>
</string-array>

        <!-- Sliding Menu item icons -->
        <array name="nav_drawer_icons">
            <item>@drawable/home</item>
            <item>@drawable/notifications</item>
            <item>@drawable/settings</item>
            <item>@drawable/about</item>
        </array>

    </resources>
```

And this s my string.xml file

Log cat :

```
10-03 11:02:06.217    6956-6956/com.example.first.fbslid E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.first.fbslid/com.example.first.fbslid.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
            at com.example.first.fbslid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method).
```

**I don't know  where am getting error as am new to android  and am trying to create sliding menu like in facebook .  Can someone Please help me to resolve**

Comment: Which is 49th line in MainActivity?

Comment: slidingMenuItems.add(new SlidingMenuItem(titles[0], icons.getResourceId(0,-1)));

Comment: You Haven't defined `nav_drawer_items` in Your String File..

Comment: before i have defined but it throws duplicate resource value

Comment: give different name and try again.. its because you have used that name somewhere else.

Comment: Your `nav_drawer_items ` maybe has been defined,but it have't item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is the

```
<!-- Sliding Menu items -->
```

that its empty, and then when you try to read the menu item array it fails

```
   titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
```

Comment: I would define as an array the items name, and then , define the icons for the items on the code
Array of strings:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013632/string-array-in-string-xml-in-android

Array of drawables:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355220/android-how-can-i-make-a-drawable-array

Comment: somebody please help me out am trying this thing for past 1 week please post your updated code

Comment: I think the problem is trying to define an array of drawables on a strings resource. Define there just the array of item names, and define on the java class which drawable corresponds to each item